# Using an if/else statement inside an each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file, js/links.json:

```
{ "allLinks": [
 {
   "Link": "http://bbc.com",
   "Poster": "John"
 },
 {
   "Link": "http://espn.com",
   "Poster": "Jane"
 }
...etc.
```

and the following HTML:

```
<input placeholder="http://" id="urlField" type="text">
<button type="button" id="search" name="button">Search</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

The behaviour I would like is:

- You enter a link into the input
- When the button is clicked, get the links.json array and loop through it.
- If the link exists, output into `#result`: "This exists, and was posted by [poster]"
- If it does not exist, output into `#result"This link does not exist."

This is how I'm trying to do it now:

```
    $(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type : 'GET',
        url : 'js/links.json',
        async : false,
        beforeSend : function(){/*loading*/},
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(jsonResult){

                $("#search").click(function() {
                    var searchValue = document.getElementById('urlField').value;

                    // Go through the whole list and find the Link name
                    var linkExists = false;
                    $.each(jsonResult.allLinks, function(i, obj) {
                            if (obj.Link === searchValue ) {
                                linkExists = true;
                                alert("It exists"); 
                                return false;
                            }
                            else {
                                linkExists = false;
                                alert("It doesn't exist");
                                return false;
                            }
                    });

                });

        }
    });
});
```

There's definitely something wrong here because, if I *don't* use the `else`, it appears to work. When I add it, it doesn't— it always defaults to "It doesn't exist."

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: the problem is, if the first item is !== serachValue, you will stop the each loop (by returning false) and linkExists will be false ... not having the else block is actually valid for your logic - or at least don't return false and don't set linkExists = false (because that would mean your logic would succeed only if the LAST element is matching

Answer (score 0):

Pull the contents of your `else` statement outside of the for loop, otherwise you `alert` failure every time you hit the first element and it doesn't produce a match.

```js
$(function() {

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'js/links.json',
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function() { /*loading*/ },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(jsonResult) {

          $("#search").click(function() {
            var searchValue = document.getElementById('urlField').value;

            // Go through the whole list and find the Link name
            var linkExists = false;
            $.each(jsonResult.allLinks, function(i, obj) {
              if (obj.Link === searchValue) {
                linkExists = true;
                alert("It exists");
                return false;
              }

            });
            if (!linkExists) {
                alert("It doesn't exist");
                return false;
            }

          });

        }
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that would ensure linkExists is false

Comment: no, because that return merely stops the each loop - a return in an inner function doesn't return from the outer function - JS 101

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful! Why does 'else' not work as part of my implementation?

Comment: Basically, `else` inside your `$.each` loop would be triggered the first time you didn't find a match, rather than when you've gone through every element and found no matches.